# Consulta SQL onde WHERE tem 2 opções

Tags: sql, query, where

Pretendo fazer uma consulta SQL onde `WHERE` tenha 2 situações, exemplo:

> SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = "%explosion%" OR tag =
>   "%explosion%"

Nesta consulta precisaria que, primeiro a consulta verifica-se se existe algum produto com o nome de `explosion` se existir parasse por ai e retornaria o resultado sem pesquisa na `tag` se também existe, mas caso não encontre registro no `name` a query iria procurar na `tag`.

Dei uma pesquisada em formas de fazer isso e a única forma que me veio é fazer 2 consultas. Fazendo primeiro a pesquisa em `name` e verificar se retorna alguma coisa e depois fazer em `tag` se `name` não retornar nada.

Talvez utilizando a *`Cláusula join`* junto com a *`Cláusula outer`* deva conseguir mas não consegui compreender o uso de outer bem para desenvolver esta query correta.

Alguem teria uma ideia de fazer isto em apenas 1 consulta sem ter que fazer malabarismo fazendo com 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou a ver uma forma de fazer sem fazer o uso de join ou subquery. Fica aqui uma solução usando a cláusula EXISTS.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products 
 WHERE name = "%explosion%"      -- Devolve os produtos com nome = '%explosion%'
    OR (                         -- Devolve os produtos com tag = '%explosion' apenas se não existir qualquer produto com nome = '%explosion%'
           tag = "%explosion%" 
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE name = '%explosion%' )
    )
```

Não indicou qual o SGBD, mas a solução proposta é portável e deverá funcionar em qualquer SGBD que implemente o standard.

Fiquei sem perceber se o nome e a tag do produto são mesmo '%explosion%' ou se pretende encontrar os registos que **contêm** essa palavra. Caso seja esse o objectivo deve trocar o `=` pelo `LIKE`.

Comment: Utilizo MySQL, funcionou perfeitamente utilizando esta forma que você comentou. Como era um exemplo que eu utilizei para explicar a duvida eu utilizei o `=` mas realmente no sistema utilizo o `LIKE`